# Dataset on molecular temperature / speed

Tags: education

I am looking for a dataset on molecular temperature / speed for educational uses, so students might model the [Boltzmann distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boltzmann_distribution). Does anyone know of such a (publicly available) dataset?